# MySQL - Calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento y presentar la edad.meses en formato decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, algoritmos

Quiero mostrar la edad en formato decimal, ejemplo fechanacimiento= 01/01/2022 , fechahoy=01/03/2023; Edad= 1.20

*Formato d/m/a*

Solución encontrada:

```
CAST(CONCAT(FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechanacimiento, CURDATE()) / 12) ,'.', (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechanacimiento, CURDATE()) % 12))AS DECIMAL(10,2));
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No entiendo bien tu pregunta, ¿has encontrado ya la solución? A ese código creo que le falta una división entre 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según tu cálculo cada mes correspondería a `0,083333333` partes  (1/12) de un año (de manera muy aproximada porque unos meses tienen más días y otros menos).

Para que tu código pueda mostrar correctamente los decimales, siguiendo la regla que has impuesto, debes dividir el resto entre el número de meses de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    CAST (
        CAST(
            FLOOR(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechanacimiento, CURDATE()) / 12
        ) AS decimal) + (
            CAST(
                (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, fechanacimiento, CURDATE()) % 12
            ) AS decimal
        ) / 12
    ) AS decimal(10,2)) diferencia
 FROM pruebas
```

Puedes ver el código SQL funcionando en el siguiente enlace:

- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2o13GiZM9f1d5Pgyrwgrv7/1